# Why does // return a float?

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, integer, floating

Why is this function printing a float if the "//" applies to integers?

```
>>> minimum = int((a + b) - math.fabs(a-b))//2      
>>> print(type(minimum))
```

Comment: Can you show [runnable code that demonstrates the problem when you run it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? In particular, show the creation of `a` and `b`. `minimum` should be an `int` in this code.

Comment: @user2357112 `a` and `b` don't matter. `m = int(whatever) // 2` is clearly `int // int`, no matter what `whatever` is.

Comment: @glglgl: I know. The point of including the creation of `a` and `b` is to make sure it's really runnable. (Also, sometimes `int(whatever)` is a long, but that's not important.) (Wait, scratch that. Python 3. `int(whatever)` is always an int, assuming the tag is correct.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you use the min function ?

Comment: @user2357112 a and b refer to the lengths of two different lists. 
Also, I should clarify, it prints and integer if i leave the 'int' at the beginning of line 1, but not without it

Comment: @YvesDaoust The code is for an assignment. The prof doesn't want us using too many pre-defined functions

Comment: "It prints an integer if I leave the `int` at the beginning of line 1, but not without it."  So your question is why `type(9//2)==int` but `type(9.0//2)==float`?  Because that's not at all what your title or written text are implying.

Comment: Then `minimum= a if a < b else b` should please him as it avoids the call to the pre-defined `fabs` ;-)

Comment: @Teepeemm I'm new to the site. Someone edited the title after I posted it. My question is why I have to write "minimum = int((a + b) - math.fabs(a-b))//2"  instead of just "minimum = ((a + b) - math.fabs(a-b))//2"

Comment: I assume they edited the title to match the first sentence.  But the answer to "why is this function printing a float" turns out to be "it's not".  The question "why is this function printing a float" "if i leave [off] the `int`" makes more sense, and leads to the accepted answer.  Other people will find this question and answer more useful if you edit the question to show how you were getting a `float` when you didn't want to.  As it stands, you are saying that you are getting a `float` when you didn't want to, but you are showing how you got the `int` you wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`//` doesn't means will return integer,  operator `//` is called (floor division), but may return float or int it depends on operand type e.g:  `9//2` is equal to `4` and `9.0//2.0` is equal to `4.0`. that is float.

> #### [5.6. Binary arithmetic operations¶](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)
>
> The `/` (division) and `//` (floor division) operators yield the quotient of their arguments. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; "the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result". Division by zero raises the ZeroDivisionError exception.

Check [ideone's link of working example](http://ideone.com/fTi0r7) for Python3._:
Following example will may be helpful to understand difference between `/` and `//` and why `//` useful (read comments):

```
a = 9.0
b = 2.0

print a//b   # floor division gives `4.0` instead of `4.5` 

a = 9
b = 2

print a/b   # int division because both `b` and `a` are `int` => `4.5`  
print a//b  # float division returns `4`

a = 9.0
b = 2

print a/b   # float division gives `4.5` because `a` is a float  
print a//b  # floor division fives `4.0`
```

Output:

```
4.0   # you doubt 
4.5   
4 
4.5   # usefulness of //
4.0
```

Now in your expression both operands are `int` so answer is int type:

```
  int((a + b) - math.fabs(a-b))  //  2 
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^      
#   int due to casting              int   => `minimum` as int
```

So `//` can result float if any operand is a float but magnitude is equals to floor.

Comment: The operands in the OP's code appear to be `int`s, though. I suspect that the OP's problem is resulting from a mere typo.

Comment: @user2357112 yes you are correct.. Can `math.fabs(a-b)` be a float ?

Comment: It's always a float. It's inside the `int` call, though.

Comment: On your second `print` statement: Python 3 is such that `9/2==4.5`.

Comment: @Teepeemm thank you very much for your correction Teepeemm I read it in Apress but because of Codepad I written wrong Now corrected thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the code is printing an integer value with the casting, but not without. What is the general rule to determine when the casting is needed?

Comment: @Manaar `//` returns int if both operands are int and magnitude is always floor, Whereas `/` returns exact division.